# Why Scaffold is inaccessible from a showDialog context?

Tags: flutter

I don't understand why I can't access my scaffold using Scaffold.of(context) from a widget inside a showDialog(...) ?
It's the same for other InheritedWidgets, but still Flutter can access Themes...
I have to manually pass the context of the showDialog caller to the widget inside showDialog.

Any ideas of the why here ?

Comment: share your code

Comment: It's a theorical question, I didn't think you need a code sample to understand it ?